# Building multi-level aggregation queries using elastic-builder.js

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query

I am trying to get my hands on javascript and elasticsearch and I was trying to create queries using the elastic-builder javascript lib.
I might be missing something which I am trying to figure out but unfortunately I am unable to.

Problem: I am trying to create multilevel aggregation like below,

```
"aggs": {
    "1": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "f1",
        "calendar_interval": "1D"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "2": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "f2",
            "calendar_interval": "1D"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "3": {
              "date_histogram": {
                "field": "f3",
                "calendar_interval": "1D"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

But what I get instead is this:

```
"aggs": {
    "1": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "f1",
        "calendar_interval": "1D"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "2": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "f2",
            "calendar_interval": "1D"
          }
        },
        "3": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "f3",
            "calendar_interval": "1D"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The current output I get has two aggregations nested in one. I am trying to build it using an array with aggregations defined in it.

The code I used is below:

```
let a = [
    esb.dateHistogramAggregation('1', "d[key]['field']").calendarInterval('1D'), 
    esb.dateHistogramAggregation('2', "d[key]['field']").calendarInterval("1D"),
    esb.dateHistogramAggregation('3', "d[key]['field']").calendarInterval("1D")
];
let m = null;
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
    if(i === 0) {
        m = a[i]
    } else {
        m.agg(a[i])
    }
}

//m = esb.dateHistogramAggregation('1', "d[key]['field']").calendarInterval('1D')
//m = m.agg(esb.dateHistogramAggregation('2', "d[key]['field']").calendarInterval("1D").agg(esb.dateHistogramAggregation('3', "d[key]['field']").calendarInterval("1D")))


esb.requestBodySearch()
    .query(
        esb.boolQuery()
            .must(esb.matchQuery('message', 'this is a test'))
            .filter(esb.termQuery('user', 'kimchy'))
            .filter(esb.termQuery('user', 'herald'))
            .should(esb.termQuery('user', 'johnny'))
            .mustNot(esb.termQuery('user', 'cassie'))
    )
    .agg(esb.termsAggregation('user_terms', 'user').agg(esb.termsAggregation('user_terms', 'user').agg(esb.termsAggregation('user_terms', 'user'))))
    .agg(m);
```

The lines commented in the code will output the result I'm expecting. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn the array into a group of sub-aggregations like so:

```
let a = [
    esb.dateHistogramAggregation('1', "d[key]['field']").calendarInterval('1D'), 
    esb.dateHistogramAggregation('2', "d[key]['field']").calendarInterval("1D"),
    esb.dateHistogramAggregation('3', "d[key]['field']").calendarInterval("1D")
];

const reqBody = esb.requestBodySearch()
    .agg(
        a[0].agg(
            a[1].agg(
                a[2]
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: I'm OK with this when I have just 3. But when it is dynamically generated then its a problem. I solved it but I don;t think its a proper way of solving it. I will post how I solved it. May be you can correct me there :)

Comment: Yes I was trying to use `.agg.apply(null, a)` but the lib doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like below. I am not sure this is right way. But someone can correct me if I am wrong.

```
    let temp = null;
    for (i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (i === a.length - 1) {
            temp = a[i];
        } else {
            temp = a[i].agg(temp)
        }
    }
```